# mysqli_query returns false for some queries

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am facing a real weird problem. Mysqli_query works fine in my localhost but not on the server.
These are the following things I have checked -

1. Php version. My localhost php version is 5.6 and even my server's php version is 5.6.
2. I checked whether the query is generated properly. The query for which I am getting false as the result is as follows :-

_

```
$qquery = "select uniqueID,question,emailgroup,email,if_read from 
  expert_questions where id=$id;";
```

which generates the following query after echo :-

```
select uniqueID,question,emailgroup,email,if_read from expert_questions where id=955;
```

Now this query, executes totally fine in the localhost and gives me perfect results in the localhost. Also I tried to execute this query in the server's database, it gives me output too.

3. I also checked whether the php files are not having mysql_connect commands, and it did have them. So I changed the whole code mysql improvised version.

The weirdest problem is that, that particular query works totally fine for ids less than 900. But it does not work for ids greater than 900 as I showed above about id=955.
Please help me out.
Thank you.

Comment: See [`mysqli_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php).

Comment: mysqli_error() returns true everytime.

Comment: No. It returns a string.

Comment: @KrishBhanushali: Eh? It returns mysqli error, or empty string. Not `true`. When `mysqli_query` returns `false`, it means that you have error in your query. Eg. missing ID.

Comment: I am sorry. It returns null.

Comment: @KrishBhanushali: Not null, maybe empty string. But if `error` returns empty string, `mysqli_query` can't return `false`.

Comment: Yes it giving me an empty string. But if I execute the same generated query in sequelPro it gives me an output.

Comment: @KrishBhanushali: so the query is fine and you have problem elsewhere. Check the error log.

Comment: No errors in the error log. It is so weird.